# Removing rows with same objects in the data frame

Tags: r

I have about 8 million rows of data frame which look like below:

```
Trevor Brown Chris Coghlan Starlin Castro Kelby Tomlinson Brandon Crawford Brandon Crawford Kelby Tomlinson Brandon Crawford

Buster Posey Chris Coghlan Starlin Castro Kelby Tomlinson Brandon Crawford Brandon Crawford Kelby Tomlinson Brandon Crawford

.
.
.
.

Trevor Brown Brandon Crawford Starlin Castro Kelby Tomlinson Brandon Crawford Brandon Crawford Kelby Tomlinson Brandon Crawford
```

A lot of rows have duplicate names and I want it removed. I find it hard to vectorize each row then check for duplicate because it takes forever, given that data frame has 8 million rows. Is there any faster way to do this task?

Comment: Is it a single string per each row?

Comment: 16 string per each row. It's 8 x 8 million data frame. Eight full names per each row

Comment: you can try `apply` and `unique`

Comment: So what kind of apply functions (e.g. lapply,rapply,sapply, and etc) would be suitable to each row of data frame?

Comment: So if I have this right: you have an 8-column data.frame, each column has names in a "first last" name format. You want to remove rows where the names are "duplicated". Is a "duplicate" row where every one of the 8 names is identical to another row, and in a identical columns? That is, same names but in a different column order would *not* be identical?

Comment: Jason: All rows are unique from one another because I ran permutation. I want to remove row that has same names in it. For example, all rows in the data frame with name "Brandon Belt" used twice, should be removed

Answer (score 0):

From what I could gather from the question and the comments, I propose this solution.

```
require(gtools)
a <- LETTERS[1:8]
data <- permutations(n = 8, r = 8, v = a)
tail(data)

#          [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
# [40315,] "H"  "G"  "F"  "E"  "D"  "A"  "B"  "C" 
# [40316,] "H"  "G"  "F"  "E"  "D"  "A"  "C"  "B" 
# [40317,] "H"  "G"  "F"  "E"  "D"  "B"  "A"  "C" 
# [40318,] "H"  "G"  "F"  "E"  "D"  "B"  "C"  "A" 
# [40319,] "H"  "G"  "F"  "E"  "D"  "C"  "A"  "B" 
# [40320,] "H"  "G"  "F"  "E"  "D"  "C"  "B"  "A"
```

Does this solve the problem? (It creates `8!` combinations with no letter repeated twice in any row)

Answer (score 0):

```
df$unique_names <- " "

for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
    df$unique_names[i]<- paste0(unique(unlist(strsplit(df$names[i]," "))),collapse=" ")

}

 df$unique_names
[1] "Trevor Brown Chris Coghlan Starlin Castro Kelby Tomlinson Brandon Crawford"
[2] "Buster Posey Chris Coghlan Starlin Castro Kelby Tomlinson Brandon Crawford"
```

## data

```
df <- data.frame(names=c("Trevor Brown Chris Coghlan Starlin Castro Kelby Tomlinson Brandon Crawford Brandon Crawford Kelby Tomlinson Brandon Crawford"
,"Buster Posey Chris Coghlan Starlin Castro Kelby Tomlinson Brandon Crawford Brandon Crawford Kelby Tomlinson Brandon Crawford"
),stringsAsFactors = F)
```